# Dependence the type of one prop on the type of other prop

Tags: typescript, react-props

Is it possible to somehow combine the description of the two types of the React component props below.

On `isEdit == true`:

```
type DialogProps = {
  isEdit: boolean
  obj: ICustom
}
```

and on `isEdit == false`:

```
type DialogProps = {
  isEdit: boolean
  obj: null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using  [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions):

```
type EditDialogProps = {isEdit: true, obj: ICustom};
type NonEditDialogProps = {isEdit: false}; // just remove obj in this one :)
type DialogProps = EditDialogProps | NonEditDialogProps;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try by making DialogProps.obj generic type

```js
type DialogProps<T> = {
  isEdit: boolean;
  obj: T extends true ? ICustom : null;
};

// Usage:
const editProps: DialogProps<true> = {
  isEdit: true,
  obj: { /* ICustom properties */ },
};
//if false
const addProps: DialogProps<false> = {
  isEdit: false,
  obj: null,
};
```

The conditional type to determine the type of the obj prop based on the value of T. When T is true, obj is of type ICustom, and when T is false, This way, you can reuse the same DialogProps type for both cases, and still maintain type safety.

Comment: I would like to pass an ICustom object to the component when `isEdit={true}` and nothing when `isEdit={false}`. In @sanu-khan example, I did not understand how this can be done using **one** component

Comment: I understood your point, i added one new method addProps which will have DialogProps as false and obj set to null

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't ask the question correct. The type definition is clear, but not the implementation of the component so that it can be called in JSX: `<Dialog isEdit={true} obj={MyObj} />` and `<Dialog isEdit={false} />`. I wanted to make a **universal** component for editing and creating.